# Postgres inherit from schema

Tags: postgresql

I am initiating a new project which will be available as a SaaS for multiple customers. So, I am thinking of creating a database and then create individual schema for every customer.

I have defined some rules and the first rule is all the customers must always have the same schema. No matter what. If one customer gets an update, all the other customers will get the update as well.

For this purpose, my question is, is it possible to inherit schema from another schema in the same database? If not, do I have to manually create all the tables and indexes in the new schema and inherit them from the tables in master schema?

I am using Postgresql 9.6 but I can upgrade it as well if needed.

I open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automated way to establish inheritance between all tables in two schemas, you'd have to do it one by one (a function can help).

However, I invite you to stop and think about your data model for a bit. How many users do you expect? If there could be many, plan differently, because databases with thousands of schemas become unwieldy (e.g. catalog lookups will become slow).

You might be better off with one schema for all users. If you are concerned with separation of the data and security, row level security might be the solution for you.

Comment: I see one problem with this approach in my scenario: At least order ids, invoice ids and customer ids for the customer of my customer, will not be sequential anymore. Can this be solved by RLS as well or do I need to generate the sequences manually?

Comment: One more question: If I use one database and one schema per customer, will it still slow down the performance if there are thousands of customers?

Comment: Having thousands of databases in one cluster is also bad, perhaps for different reasons: a) harder to tune autovacuum (so many tables to handle!) b) wasted space through thousands of system catalogs (which also feeds into the other problem).

Comment: If you are thinking about a "gap-less sequence", forget about the idea if you possibly can. Even with a table + sequence per customer, you will still get gaps (rollback). That's just fine usually. Gap-less sequences are hard to create and hurt concurrency massively (see the many SO posts). The main point here is: even if you need it, it would probably not be worse with one table for all customers than with one table per customer.

Comment: Thanks. I have decided to go with signle schema with RLS approach.