# Seemingly not possible to inherit postgres schemas. Is there a good reason for this?

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, database-schema

**TLDR**
It seems like inheritance between Postgres schemas isn't supported. Why is this?
[SO post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012783/postgres-inherit-from-schema/50015408#50015408)
[SO post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197477/postgres-new-schema-to-inherit-permissions-for-a-user/52197648#52197648)

I have a dataset available to one group of customers (A). Another group of customers (B) would like to add to this dataset and have additional, private data on top of the default dataset. We're considering leveraging postgres schemas for this-- the default dataset would be accessed via `public.tablename` and the private dataset would be accessed via `B.tablename`.

`B` should be able to use our application and transition easily between the public and private datasets since they're superusers. This means the tables behind their `B` schema will need to have the same relationships as in the `public` schema, but it would sure be nice to be able to inherit everything from `public` rather than having to do it manually.

So far, I haven't seen anything about schema inheritance being possible either in the documentation, in blog posts, or here. I'm basically writing this post to confirm that this is in fact true, and also soliciting opinions on if this use case isn't well suited for schemas.

Comment: You could use a single schema and a where condition to select the records for A or B. You could row level security, just to be sure. Using a database superuser role would be the worst thing ever, that's something to avoid anyway.

Comment: You can't inherit schemas. Create as schema for  the private data and then a view that combines that with the public data.